# videojs return vdata error when dispose is call

Tags: jquery, video.js, gsap

I'm getting an error and i dont find any clues, i'm using videojs to control multiple video in a slider, on each completed transition, i call a new instance of videojs and and store the ID into a variable and dispose() the old videojs. Since i have lot of slide (or videos) and want to kill them when there are not active for performance. My slider work under TweenMax.. and i call the dispose() in the onStart event from a Timline. When the dispose() is called, i'm getting this error :

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vdata1408997779453' of null**

This is a sample of my code :

```
var $slides = [],
    videos =[],
    currentSlide = 0,
    currentVideo = null;

$(function(){

    TweenLite.to($('#header-wrap'), 1, {
            left: x,
            onStart: function(){
                if(currentVideo) {
                    TweenMax.set($('.video-holder'), {autoAlpha: 0});
                    currentVideo.dispose();
                }
            },

            onComplete: function() {
                if(videos[slideActive].url) {
                        videojs('movie-video-holder-'+slideActive+'', {"autoplay": false, "preload": "auto", "controls": false, "lopp": false}, function(){
                            currentVideo = $vid;
                            [...]
                        });
                }
            }
    [...]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This looks like it's related to https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/1481

A really nasty hack (until the patch is merged) would be to pause the player, wait for the frame after the error, then dispose of the player:

```
player.pause();
setTimeout(function() {
    player.dispose();
}, 0);
```

Comment: Upvoting this as it fixed my [similar] issue. I was using videojs inside an Angularjs directive and had a listener which on $destroy would dispose the player. There seemed to be a race condition where angular would clean the DOM (switch states) before videojs had finished disposing. This caused videojs to spam the console with errors

Comment: You sir are a champion.  This has been driving me absolutely crazy.

Comment: This is crazy that the answer is still a hack. I started using video.js today as it was showcased on Github but am not at all impressed with it. The documentation and API reference makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could solve this was overriding videojs prototype method `trackCurrentTime` adding a check over `this.player().el()`, as they have some [issues](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1574) [related](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1484) [to this](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1431) [error](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1505).

```
vjs.MediaTechController.prototype.trackCurrentTime = function() {
    if (this.currentTimeInterval) { this.stopTrackingCurrentTime(); }

    this.currentTimeInterval = setInterval(vjs.bind(this, function(){
        if(this.player().el() != null)
            this.player().trigger('timeupdate');
        else
            clearInterval(this.currentTimeInterval);

    }), 250);
};
```

The problem comes when you pause then play manually the player and dispose it while playing. After that, the interval `currentTimeInterval` never gets stopped.

I bet they are working on fixing it as the issues are confirmed. Meanwhile try this fix